# How to make A-Frame cursor interact only with the closest object

Tags: cursor, aframe, interaction

I am writing an A-Frame project. I have some questions of cursor.

Is it possible to set the 'near' for the a-entity tag with attribute 'cursor'?

And the cursor emit the event of the object behind my target object, what is the reason and how to solve it?

This is the code of my cursor:

```
    <a-entity id="cursor"
              cursor="fuse: false"
              position="0.000 0.000 -0.1"
              geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.0008; radiusOuter: 0.0013"
              material="color: black; shader: flat"
              near="5"
              showLine="true"
              cursor-submit
    >
    </a-entity>
```

Project: https://github.com/LeMueller/skills-lab-web

Live Demo: http://webvr.virtualskillslab.de/

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Hey, it seems to be working correctly, both on the "scene" mouse cursor, and the camera one http://jsfiddle.net/mfq5dhok/6/ seem to fire the event only upon the first entity it meets

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski Thank you. But actualy I can get the bottle after the door without opning the door. I record a shot video to show that: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xkvE5RWdaYckK2q3ZvpLEhCjqXxeRrWF/view

Answer (score 1):

If you want to (and you should) whitelist the objects you want to intersect, set the `raycaster.objects` property.

```
<a-entity cursor raycaster="objects: [data-raycastable]"

<a-sphere data-i-am-not-raycastable></a-sphere>
<a-box data-raycastable></a-box>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, that there are two succesive objects I what to interact. But the cursor emit the eventlistener of the object back first, as the video shows: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xkvE5RWdaYckK2q3ZvpLEhCjqXxeRrWF/view. Is there something wrong by the cursor about it?